# Order of convergence of Newton's method for $g(x) = xe ^{x/2} - 1 + x$

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

The question is for a Matlab course and it is the following:

Study the order of convergence of Newton's method on the function
 $ g(x) = xe ^{x/2}  -1 -x $ .
Find the solution of accurate within $10^{-5}$, starting from $x_0 = 2.5$. Is it
quadratic?

So I wrote a Matlab program for Newton's method. And it gave me an approximate root $x^*$ and the estimated error.

I'm having trouble understanding and applying the quadratic convergence definition.

My idea is to check $|x_{i-1}-x^*| / |x_{i}-x^*|^2$ in each step and see if its converging. Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please show us what work you have done towards this, and explain where you are stuck This will help people give an answer which is at your level and doesn't repeat things you already know. In this case, a good place to start would be to state what you know about convergences being quadratic

Comment: Also add the exact formulation of your task. E.g., are you to investigate the properties of the function or to make numerical experiments?

Comment: It would help if you could just paste the result of your computation, it should be a table with not more than 7 data lines. Use code formatting if for easy formatting, 4 spaces at the start of each line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct and should result in

```
k        x[k]          f(x[k])         dx[k]      dx[k]/dx[k-1]^2

0    2.500000000000000 10.2259       -1.155037e+00  -1.155037e+00
1    1.344962880055704  2.97987      -6.967936e-01  -5.222906e-01
2    0.648169320860770  0.544435     -1.923188e-01  -3.961079e-01
3    0.455850509909319  0.0283948    -1.116912e-02  -3.019781e-01
4    0.444681389050070  8.70351e-05  -3.444617e-05  -2.761232e-01
5    0.444646942882529  8.23361e-10  -3.258703e-10  -2.746395e-01
6    0.444646942556658 -1.11022e-16   4.394048e-17   4.137855e+02
```

for the iteration formula in the title ($g(x)=...+x$) and

```
k        x[k]          f(x[k])         dx[k]      dx[k]/dx[k-1]^2

0  2.500000000000000  5.22586      -7.625347e-01  -7.625347e-01
1  1.737465307480700  1.40446      -4.065176e-01  -6.991336e-01
2  1.330947690963831  0.258294     -1.153082e-01  -6.977523e-01
3  1.215639529705251  0.0167891    -8.598166e-03  -6.466745e-01
4  1.207041363790715  8.83367e-05  -4.572034e-05  -6.184403e-01
5  1.206995643450354  2.48783e-09  -1.287697e-09  -6.160199e-01
6  1.206995642162657  4.44089e-16  -2.298597e-16  -1.386231e+02
```

for the iteration as formulated in the text ($g(x)=...-x$).

Both nicely show quadratic convergence until the number of available digits runs out.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I was expecting convergence to 0.444647 according to wolfram alpha

Comment: You are right, I transcribed the function as $…-x$ instead of $…+x$. The constant in the last column is less constant as before, but still enough for quadratic convergence.